# UNIX - Count occurrences of character per line between two fields and add new column with result

Tags: bash, unix, merge, count

I have a PLINK ped file that looks like this:

```
ACS_D132        ACS_D132        0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1
ACS_D140        ACS_D140        0       0       2       2       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1     1 1     2 1     1 1
ACS_D141        ACS_D141        0       0       2       2       2 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1
ACS_D147        ACS_D147        0       0       2       2       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1     1 1     1 1     1 1
ACS_D155        ACS_D155        0       0       1       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1
ACS_D196        ACS_D196        0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1
ACS_D221        ACS_D221        0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1
```

I am interested in counting how many time the string "2" occurs between the 7th field (included) and the last field. Then, if the number of occurrences is:

- 0: add 1 (being absent) to the new last field
- 1: add 2 (being present) to the new last field
- 2: add 2 (being present) to the new last field

The output would be:

```
ACS_D132        ACS_D132        0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1
ACS_D140        ACS_D140        0       0       2       2       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1     1 1     2 1     1 1     2
ACS_D141        ACS_D141        0       0       2       2       2 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1     2
ACS_D147        ACS_D147        0       0       2       2       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2
ACS_D155        ACS_D155        0       0       1       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1
ACS_D196        ACS_D196        0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1
ACS_D221        ACS_D221        0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1
```

I know that to count the occurence of a string in every field I can use:

> grep -n -o "2" file1  | sort -n | uniq -c | cut -d : -f 1

And that I can merge the 2 results using:

> paste -d' ' file1 file2 > file3

But I don't know how to count the occurrences between two fields.

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk to check for column, row based data:

```
awk '{c=0; for(i=7; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==2) c++; if (c<2) c++; print $0, c}' file

ACS_D132        ACS_D132        0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1 1
ACS_D140        ACS_D140        0       0       2       2       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1     1 1     2 1     1 1 2
ACS_D141        ACS_D141        0       0       2       2       2 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1 2
ACS_D147        ACS_D147        0       0       2       2       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1     1 1     1 1     1 1 2
ACS_D155        ACS_D155        0       0       1       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1 1
ACS_D196        ACS_D196        0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1 1
ACS_D221        ACS_D221        0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ape 's/$/" " . (1 + !! grep 2 == $_, @F[6 .. $#F])/e'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints the result
- `-a` splits each input line on whitespace into the @F array
- `grep` in scalar context returns the count, by !! (double negation) we change it to 0 or 1, and by adding 1 we make it into 1 and 2 as requested
- s/// substitutes $ (end of line) with the result of the code in the replacement part (that's what /e does)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for your quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk '{s=0;for(i=7;i<=NF;i++) if($i==2) s+=1; s=s==0?1:2; print $0, s;}' data.txt
```

**Explanations:**

- The instructions between the `{}` are executed on each line of the file.
- NF is the number of fields in the line. They are numbered 1 to NF and you can access them with the $n notation.